# Why is turf.booleanCrosses returning false for lineString and Bbox

Tags: turf

I have a lineString and a Bbox and I want to check if the linestring ever goes through the bbox. I tried using turf.booleanCrosses() but it's always returning false.

Here is my code and the logs:

```
console.log("boundingBox =", boundingBox)
const lineString = turf.lineString(coordinates);
console.log("lineString = ", JSON.stringify(lineString))
const box = turf.bboxPolygon(boundingBox)
console.log("box=", JSON.stringify(box))
const crossesBoundingBox = turf.booleanCrosses(lineString, box);
console.log("crossesBoundingBox =", crossesBoundingBox)
```

and the logs

```
LOG  boundingBox = [-38.22199669924828, 145.03160513620344, -38.219342153022794, 145.03352405620296]
LOG  lineString =  {"type":"Feature","properties":{},"geometry":{"type":"LineString","coordinates":[[145.03224,-38.22133],[145.03223,-38.22086],[145.03219,-38.22058],[145.03224,-38.22006],[145.03228,-38.2198],[145.03248,-38.21934],[145.0326,-38.21912],[145.03289,-38.2187],[145.03304,-38.21853],[145.03318,-38.21831],[145.03338,-38.21811],[145.03412,-38.21728],[145.0341,-38.21701],[145.03405,-38.21677],[145.03392,-38.21654],[145.03358,-38.21605],[145.03353,-38.21594],[145.03356,-38.21593],[145.03328,-38.21553],[145.03319,-38.21524],[145.03335,-38.21505],[145.03341,-38.21504],[145.03358,-38.21514],[145.03382,-38.21523],[145.03387,-38.21529],[145.03437,-38.21536],[145.03464,-38.21542],[145.03469,-38.21545],[145.03472,-38.21542],[145.03492,-38.21549],[145.03497,-38.21553],[145.03516,-38.21549],[145.03549,-38.21546],[145.03578,-38.21555],[145.03599,-38.21571],[145.0361,-38.2159],[145.03602,-38.21604],[145.03589,-38.21608],[145.03565,-38.21621],[145.0354,-38.21641],[145.03494,-38.21669],[145.03475,-38.21685],[145.03453,-38.21699],[145.03434,-38.21715],[145.0341,-38.21732],[145.03373,-38.21775],[145.03317,-38.21834],[145.03305,-38.21854],[145.03289,-38.21875],[145.03261,-38.21917],[145.03237,-38.21963],[145.03224,-38.2201],[145.03221,-38.22036],[145.03221,-38.22058],[145.03226,-38.22104],[145.03231,-38.22174],[145.03234,-38.22195],[145.03233,-38.22242],[145.0324,-38.22319],[145.0324,-38.22346],[145.03236,-38.22325],[145.03234,-38.22298],[145.03237,-38.22295]]}}
LOG  box= {"type":"Feature","bbox":[-38.22199669924828,145.03160513620344,-38.219342153022794,145.03352405620296],"properties":{},"geometry":{"type":"Polygon","coordinates":[[[-38.22199669924828,145.03160513620344],[-38.219342153022794,145.03160513620344],[-38.219342153022794,145.03352405620296],[-38.22199669924828,145.03352405620296],[-38.22199669924828,145.03160513620344]]]}}
LOG  crossesBoundingBox = false
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Switch your bounding box from `[-38.22199669924828, 145.03160513620344, -38.219342153022794, 145.03352405620296]` to `[145.03160513620344, -38.22199669924828, 145.03352405620296, -38.219342153022794]` as you can see that transforming `boundingBox` to `box` with `turf.bboxPolygon` generate pair of coordinates in the "wrong order". The expected order of coordinates in https://turfjs.org/docs/#bboxPolygon is an "*extent in minX, minY, maxX, maxY order*"

Corrected sample below

```js
const boundingBox = [145.03160513620344, -38.22199669924828, 145.03352405620296, -38.219342153022794];
console.log("boundingBox =", boundingBox)
const coordinates = [[145.03224,-38.22133],[145.03223,-38.22086],[145.03219,-38.22058],[145.03224,-38.22006],[145.03228,-38.2198],[145.03248,-38.21934],[145.0326,-38.21912],[145.03289,-38.2187],[145.03304,-38.21853],[145.03318,-38.21831],[145.03338,-38.21811],[145.03412,-38.21728],[145.0341,-38.21701],[145.03405,-38.21677],[145.03392,-38.21654],[145.03358,-38.21605],[145.03353,-38.21594],[145.03356,-38.21593],[145.03328,-38.21553],[145.03319,-38.21524],[145.03335,-38.21505],[145.03341,-38.21504],[145.03358,-38.21514],[145.03382,-38.21523],[145.03387,-38.21529],[145.03437,-38.21536],[145.03464,-38.21542],[145.03469,-38.21545],[145.03472,-38.21542],[145.03492,-38.21549],[145.03497,-38.21553],[145.03516,-38.21549],[145.03549,-38.21546],[145.03578,-38.21555],[145.03599,-38.21571],[145.0361,-38.2159],[145.03602,-38.21604],[145.03589,-38.21608],[145.03565,-38.21621],[145.0354,-38.21641],[145.03494,-38.21669],[145.03475,-38.21685],[145.03453,-38.21699],[145.03434,-38.21715],[145.0341,-38.21732],[145.03373,-38.21775],[145.03317,-38.21834],[145.03305,-38.21854],[145.03289,-38.21875],[145.03261,-38.21917],[145.03237,-38.21963],[145.03224,-38.2201],[145.03221,-38.22036],[145.03221,-38.22058],[145.03226,-38.22104],[145.03231,-38.22174],[145.03234,-38.22195],[145.03233,-38.22242],[145.0324,-38.22319],[145.0324,-38.22346],[145.03236,-38.22325],[145.03234,-38.22298],[145.03237,-38.22295]]
const lineString = turf.lineString(coordinates);
console.log("lineString = ", JSON.stringify(lineString))
const box = turf.bboxPolygon(boundingBox)
console.log("box=", JSON.stringify(box))
const crossesBoundingBox = turf.booleanCrosses(lineString, box);
// Will return true now
console.log("crossesBoundingBox =", crossesBoundingBox)
```

Comment: thankyou very much, that solved it!